# C++ - Send IOCTL command to WBF to get sensor attributes on Windows

Tags: windows, c++11, ioctl

I'm trying to understand how I can retrieve the WINBIO_SENSOR_ATTRIBUTES buffer by using WBF APIs. 
I found this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff536431

It mentions about sending IOCTL command, however, I'm not able to understand how exactly I can invoke this from C++ code and receive the sensor attributes structure. Can anybody help? or point me to some sample code which does the similar stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take a look at [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is the function to which you must supply the `IOCTL_BIOMETRIC_GET_ATTRIBUTES` value as the second parameter to obtain the biometric data (the link you included describes how to handle the size ouf the output buffer - first supply a `DWORD` sized buffer to get the actual size of the output and then allocate a properly sized buffer and retrieve the actual data). But to do this you also need a valid device handle (first parameter of [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx)). This handle should be obtained by calling [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) and passing the device name of the driver. If you do not know the PDO then either you can try looking in Device Manager if the shows that to you under the "Details" tab or you have to use the SetupDi* family functions to enumerate the biometrics device class and get the name from there.